# How do you remove parent records that don't have any children in a Biztalk Map?

Tags: xml, mapping, biztalk

Imagine you have the following source data with a parent-children relationship between a Box and its Cakes.

```
<Box id = 1>
   <Cakes>
    <Cake id =1>
            <some other tags ...>
    </Cake>
    <Cake id =2>
            <some other tags ...>
    </Cake>
   </Cakes>   
</Box>
<Box id = 2>    
    <Cakes/>   
</Box>
```

The goal is to properly remove the boxes that contain no cakes (such as box 2) in the destination, while keeping the ability to map the Cake elements and their children tags properly in the graphical mapper (so without using a raw XSLT expression that would prevent that).

Is there a nice way to do this using functoids? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if the `id` attribute of the first `Cake` child of the current `Box` returns an empty string.

---

You get the desired transformation using the following functoids:

1) insert **Iteration** functoid and connect to `Box` node

2) insert **Index** functoid and connect to `id` attribute of `Cake` node

3) connect **Index** functoid to **Iteration** functoid (output side)

4) insert **Not Equal** functoid and connect to **Index** functoid (output side)

5) configure **Not Equal** functiod input; add empty string constant

6) connect **Not Equal** output to target message `Box` node

7) insert **Value Mapping** functoid

8) connect **Not Equal** output to **Value Mapping** input side

9) connect `id` attribute of source message `Box` node to **Value Mapping** input

10) connect **Value Mapping** output to `id` attribute of target message `Box` node

---

Sorry I can't provide a screenshot right now; I hope you can figure out from my description.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit one dimensional when it comes to mapping, but we invariably use the mapper to prototype our XSLT and then switch the map to using a Custom XSLT stylesheet

See these SO posts [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088419/biztalk-force-empty-elements-to-be-created-without-using-xslt-call-template) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716608/biztalk-2010-mapping-an-xsd-with-a-lot-of-elements-with-the-same-name/3718014#3718014) on how to convert the map to XSLT

Your XSLT will look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
        xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
        exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var userCSharp"
        version="1.0"
        xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">

    <xsl:output
        omit-xml-declaration="no"
        method="xml"
        version="1.0"
        encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Boxes" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Boxes">
        <MappedBoxes>
            <xsl:for-each select="Box[count(Cakes/Cake) > 0]">
                <MappedBox>
                    <MappedCakes>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Cakes/Cake">
                            <MappedCake>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Tag/text()" />
                            </MappedCake>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </MappedCakes>
                </MappedBox>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </MappedBoxes>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This was the XML I used

```
<Boxes>
    <Box id = "1">
        <Cakes>
            <Cake id ="1">
                <Tag>FirstCake</Tag>
            </Cake>
            <Cake id ="2">
                <Tag>SecondCake</Tag>
            </Cake>
        </Cakes>
    </Box>
    <Box id = "2">
        <Cakes/>
    </Box>
    <Box id = "3">
    </Box>
    <Box id = "4">
        <Cakes>
            <Cake id ="4">
                <Tag>FourthCake</Tag>
            </Cake>
            <Cake id ="5">
                <Tag>FifthCake</Tag>
            </Cake>
        </Cakes>
    </Box>
</Boxes>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a lot of visual mapping done (the <some other tags ...> part is actually very complex and deep, and already all done with the visual mapper and tested). So it won't do for that case to use a custom XSLT like this. I would need a solution using the capabilities of the visual mapper of biztalk.

Comment: View the source of your *.btm.cs files and see what VS does with your visual maps ;)

Comment: I get the idea but that kinda defeats the purpose of using Biztalk doesn't it? If I just want to write custom XSLT I can do that in my .NET apps directly ... and that solution needs to be readable / maintainable to someone who isn't that deeply technical.