# Problem with BizTalk multi-input map

Tags: mapping, biztalk

I have a map that takes 2 input messages, like this:

```
<ns0:Root>
   <InputMessagePart_0>
      <root>
         <Indicator>1</Indicator>
         <NewValue>AAA</NewValue>
      </root>
   <InputMessagePart_0>
   <InputMessagePart_1>
      <root>
         <Value>BBB</Value>
      </root>
   <InputMessagePart_1>
</ns0:Root>
```

(Lots of the nodes are not shown for clarity)
The ouput message looks like this:

```
<Root>
   <Value>AAA</Value>
</Root>
```

(It's identical to InputMessagePart_1)

If the Indicator is 1, I want Value to be replaced with NewValue. If it's 0, I want Value to stay the same. I used a scripting functoid with code like this:

```
public string Get_Value(string indicator, string value, string newValue)
{
   if(indicator == "1")
   {
      return newValue;
   }
   else
   {
      return value;
   }
}
```

I'm running into problems due to the fact that Value might not actually occur in the original InputMessagePart_1 - if it doesn't, I want to create it. With the script above, even though Indicator is 1, I'm not getting a return string when Value doesn't exist.

Any suggestions?

Updated: I did some further testing by removing the if/then logic and just returned a hard-coded string from the functoid, and I get the same results... it seems that just having the empty input kills the entire functionality of the functoid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should want to use the [Equal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559045(v=bts.20).aspx) functoid and test whether the value is `1`. You'll then feed the result to the input of two functoids:

- First, to a [Value Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee250680(v=bts.10).aspx) functoid, which is connected to the `<New Value>` tag in the first part of the source schema.
- Second, to a [Logical Not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547117(v=bts.20).aspx) functoid, which is *then* connected to another Value Mapping functoid connected to the `<Value>` tag in the second part of the source schema.

[image]

If the `<Indicator>`; tag does not contain the expected value `1` or is not present in the source message, the Logical Equal functoid will return `False`, and the second branch of the map will execute.

It doesn't matter whether the `Value` tag is present in the second part of the source schema. If it is not, either one of the Value Mapping functoids will create it in the destination.

If you definitely need to depend upon the `<Indicator>` tag, you might want to use the [Logical Existence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559386(BTS.10).aspx) functoid, that returns whether any specified input node appears in the source message.

Comment: Either that doesn't work, or I didn't follow what you are saying... I ran the Value node (from InputMessagePart_1) into the Logical Existence functoid, and ran the output to a Value Mapping functoid. The second input of the VM is the Value node. The output of the VM goes into the if/then scripting functoid (since I still need to look at whether Indicator is 1 or 0), but the result is the same - if the Value node doesn't exist, I can't create it and populate it with NewValue when Indicator = 1.

Comment: No, Indicator will always exist in the top of the two schemas - Value is optional in the bottom schema, but I'll try the way you suggested...

Comment: I tried this, and while it works on a simplified test schema, it fails when I apply it to the real thing, probably because I'm dealing with a looping HIPAA schema. I was all set to post a screenshot, but reputation isn't high enough... As soon as I connect that bottom Value Mapping to the destination, I lose it... delete the connection and it works fine. Thanks though, I'm guessing I'm going in a better direction at least.

Comment: Bill, as for your original question, I feel that my answer is correct... and should be identified as such. Otherwise, could you update your question with a more meaningful example?

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails using the mapper, you might try switching to XSLT - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716608/biztalk-2010-mapping-an-xsd-with-a-lot-of-elements-with-the-same-name/3718014#3718014) how to scrape the XSLT out of your existing BTM.

The map that you are after looks straightforward:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > .. etc ... whatever you've scraped out
    <xsl:output ...
    <xsl:template match=...>

<ns1:Root>
<ns1:Value>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/ns0:Root/ns0:InputMessagePart_0/ns0:root/ns0:Indicator/text()='1'">
            <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:Root/ns0:InputMessagePart_0/ns0:root/ns0:NewValue/text()" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:Root/ns0:InputMessagePart_1/ns0:root/ns0:Value/text()" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
<ns1:Value>
</ns1:Root>
```