# How not to map element when value is missing in Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk

I don't want to in the output document to write out the element attribute if the value is missing or is an empty string. 
How to do that? 
That's in a biztalk mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer doing the XSLT yourself:
(I'm checking for missing element, empty value, and `xsi:nil` - delete accordingly if not applicable)

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(s0:inElement) 
                    or s0:inElement[normalize-space(.) = ''] 
                    or string(s0:inElement/@xsi:nil) = 'true'">
        ... Default here, e.g. leave this blank, 
            ... or if you want nil then <ns1:outElement xsi:nil="true"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <ns1:outElement>
            <xsl:value-of select="s0:inElement/text()" />
        </ns1:outElement>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: the xslt solution looks nice.

Comment: Have a look here to see how to convert a visual map to XSLT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716608/biztalk-2010-mapping-an-xsd-with-a-lot-of-elements-with-the-same-name/3718014#3718014

Answer (score 8):

To suppress an element in the destination, use a value mapping functoid.

1. connect the element in question to a `LOGICAL EXISTENCE` functoid.
2. connect the `LOGICAL EXISTENCE` functoid to a `LOGICAL AND` functoid.
3. connect the element functoid to a `NOT EQUALS` functoid.
4. In the `NOT EQUALS` functoid, set the Condition2 to BLANK.
5. connect the `NOT EQUALS` functoid to the `LOGICAL AND` functoid.
6. connect the `LOGICAL AND` functoid to the `VALUE MAP` functoid.
7. connect the element to the `VALUE MAP` functoid.
8. connect the `VALUE MAP` functoid to the destination element.

Do these steps in order. The screen shot below should help:

[image: sample map]

HTH

Comment: I just usually just use the > functoid and compare if it is > than a single space. Then you have one logical functoid instead of 3.