# New line issue in HL7 message of BizTalk 2009

Tags: xml, dictionary, biztalk, hl7

I have to generate HL7 message with my XML as input message. I am facing some different scenario over here.

Issue: If we receive “Enter” (\r\n) character in some of fields in input XML message. The final HL7 file gets break at the point where that field is used in HL7 message. This makes HL7 message invalid and because of this our destination system rejects that message.

I have tried following approaches:

**1.    Map** 
•   The XML message received in orch is transformed into another XML message by using the same schema. We tried following different ways in map.
o   script functoid is used to assign Empty value if Input field consists of \r\n value. OR
o   XSLT is used to tranform Input XML message to output by checking the value in input field OR
o   Simple one to one mapping is used to tranform Input XML message to output XML message

**Output**
•   With above three approaches output XML message is NULL only.

**2.    Class Library**
•   The XML message received in orch is passed as a input to C# function.
•   Please find following code:

**Output**
o   The output XML from that function is without new line (\r\n).  But the final HL7 message breaks at that field only.

public static  XmlDocument RemoveNewLineCharacters(XLANGMessage msg)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc =(XmlDocument)msg[0].RetrieveAs(typeof(XmlDocument));

```
        XmlDocument XmlIndentedMessage = new XmlDocument();

        string IndentedMessage = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder StrBldr = new StringBuilder();

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.Indent = true;

        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

        XmlWriter writer;

        writer = XmlWriter.Create(StrBldr, settings);

        xmlDoc.Save(writer);

        IndentedMessage = StrBldr.ToString();

        XmlIndentedMessage.LoadXml(IndentedMessage);

        writer.Close();

        return XmlIndentedMessage;
    }
```

Any help to resolve this issue really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm  a little confused at your question, but if I understand correctly, you need to remove the new line sequence that might be in a XML element.  I would attempt to build a pre-processor (encode/de-code) in a pipeline component before the message type is identified and tagged on the message context in an orchestration.  You have more low level control over the messages in the pipeline than in an orchestration. I would not recommend doing this type of XML manipulation in a orchestration if possible but if you need to do in an orchestration I would do it in XSLT as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375634/biztalk-hl7-send-pipeline-error-due-to-line-breaks-in-empty-xml-elements).  Hope that helps.