# BizTalk mapping issue

Tags: mapping, biztalk

I've got a mapping issue which I'm trying to solve in the mapping tool of BizTalk.

Consider the following input file:

```xml
<person>
    <ID>APersonID</ID>
    <relatives>
        <relative>
            <name>Relative name 1</name>
        </relative>
        <relative>
            <name>Relative name 2</name>
        </relative>
    </relatives>
</person>
```

Note:  **minOccurs** of the relative element is set to *0* and the **maxOccurs** of the relative element is set to *unbounded*.

This input should be mapped to the following output:

```xml
<relatives>
    <person>
        <ID>APersonID</ID>
        <relative>Relative name 1</relative>
    </person>
    <person>
        <ID>APersonID</ID>
        <relative>Relative name 2</relative>
    </person>
<relatives>
```

Note: The person element has a **minOccurs** of *1* and a **maxOccurs** of *unbounded*.

I've got the mapping to work with a Looping functoid that links the relative element of the input file to the person element in the output file.But now there is a situation in which I'm given the following input file:

```xml
<person>
    <ID>APersonID</ID>
    <relatives />
</person>
```

Which should be mapped to

```xml
<relatives>
    <person>
        <ID>APersonID</ID>
    </person>
<relatives>
```

My current mapping can't handle this situation. Can somebody give suggestions on how to make/edit the mapping so that both situations can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are a bit more complex than at first seems since we need to test for existence of at least one `relatives/relative` before progressing. I can't think of any other way than to use XSLT - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716608/biztalk-2010-mapping-an-xsd-with-a-lot-of-elements-with-the-same-name/3718014#3718014) on how to extract the XSLT from your map and change the BTM to use an XSLT instead of the visual function mapping.

The following XSLT

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalk_Server_Project5.Schema1">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns0:person" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ns0:person">
        <relatives>
            <xsl:variable name="personId" select="ns0:ID/text()" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(ns0:relatives) or not(ns0:relatives/ns0:relative)">
                    <person>
                        <ID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$personId" />
                        </ID>
                    </person>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:relatives/ns0:relative">
                        <person>
                            <ID>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$personId" />
                            </ID>
                            <relative>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:name/text()" />
                            </relative>
                        </person>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </relatives>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the output you've described. (Obviously change your namespaces to match, and I've assumed you've got `elementFormDefault="qualified"` (If not, drop the `ns0` prefixes)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, making a custom XSLT solved my problem.