# Enrich message from within same message

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Using Biztalk 2010 I have a incoming message with this structure:

```
<xml><blocks>
<block id="level">
<message id="code">100</message>
<message id="description">Some description</message>
</block>
<block id="level">
<message id="code">101</message>
<message id="description">More description</message>
</block>
</blocks>
<blocks>
<block id="change">
<message id="table">1</message>
<message id="oldvalue">100</message>
<message id="newvalue">101</message>
</block>
</blocks>
</xml>
```

I need to map the above to this structure:

```
<terms>
<termItem>
<code>100</code>
<description>Some description</description>
<deleted>false</deleted>
</termItem>
<termItem>
.....and so on with values from the above xml file, except that the item from the "change" block should be added as a new record to output, so the total output will be 3 items (<block>).
```

The map view is like this: [image]

I need some help in choosing the right combination of either functoids to use, or maybe another approach to solve this challenge.

I'm able to either choose all blocks with the "level" value and filter out the "change" block, but unable to make a combination of the two.

Any hints, suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be more than meets the eye

1. The incoming xml seems to be nested (as per the schema in the visual mapper), so the example input xml structure might not quite be right?
2. Also, it might be that the schema on the RHS is debatched, i.e. one PaymentTerms message per company id, so unless you only need to map the first Company, you will need to create a wrapper schema for all mapped companies, with an arbitrary root node, and then debatch them before sending.

That said, it is relatively straightforward to get the general structure of the output by using a [custom xslt instead of the visual mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716608/biztalk-2010-mapping-an-xsd-with-a-lot-of-elements-with-the-same-name/3718014#3718014). I've assumed the RHS schema on your diagram for the real output schema (not your terms example).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <!--Outer template-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <PaymentTerms CompanyCode="Unsure">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </PaymentTerms>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Root blocks only-->
  <xsl:template match="block[@id='level']">
    <PaymentTerm>
      <Code>
        <xsl:value-of select="message[@id='code']/text()"/>
      </Code>
      <Description>
        <xsl:value-of select="message[@id='description']/text()"/>
      </Description>
      <Deleted>
        <!--No idea how you want this populated-->
        <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
      </Deleted>
    </PaymentTerm>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="blocks/block"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Nested blocks only-->
  <xsl:template match="block[@id='change']">
    <PaymentTerm>
      <Code>
        NestedCode
      </Code>
      <Description>
        NestedDescription
      </Description>
      <Deleted>
        NestedDeleted
      </Deleted>
    </PaymentTerm>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You didn't provide much info on how the nested blocks are to be mapped, so I've provided placeholders in the meantime.

HTH!

Comment: Hi HTH,

thanks, and yes I can see that I missed out something in my question, so here's an update. I got hold of some real output from the source system. The output is supposed to be mapped to the target for all "block id="Payment Terms" and for all "Change Log Entry" where the field "Type of Change" == 2. This should hopefully make it more clear :-)

The input xml is here: [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/970327/xml_input.xml) and expected output https://dl.dropbox.com/u/970327/xml_output.xml. Thanks - Cheers Frank

Comment: Thanks, got the problem solved using custom xslt with the map. So thanks HTH for the input.

Comment: @user155814 - glad it helped - apols, didn't get time today to look at your updated xml. #DayTimeJobSucks ;)