# In Biztalk, how do I split an envelope with an extra element?

Tags: biztalk, pipeline, orchestration

I'm trying to split an incoming message in the following form:

```
 <Items>
    <BatchID>123</BatchID>
    <Item>...</Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
  </Items>
```

I've a pipeline with a XML disassembler which takes the Items schema and outputs the Item schema. On the Items schema, the Envelope property is set to `true`, and the "Body XPath" property points to the Items element.

However, when I try to process a file, I get the error: `Finding the document specification by message type "BatchID" failed. Verify the schema deployed properly.`, presumably because it's expect only Item elements, and it doesn't know what to do with the BatchID element.

If I make the BatchID an attribute on the Items element (like a sensible person would have), everything works fine.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the layout.

At this time, I do not care what is the value of BatchID.

How do I get it to split the message?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the Xml disassembler always extracts *all child nodes* of the specified `body_xpath` element - it would have been a nice feature to be able to specify Item Xpath instead :(.

You can workaround this limitation by either:

- Creating a schema for the undesirable `<BatchID>` element, and then just eat instances of it, e.g. creating a subscribing send port using TomasR's [Null Adapter](http://winterdom.com/dev/bts/)
- or, Transform the envelope in a map on the receive port, before the envelope is debatched, where the transform strips out the unwanted `Batch` element

The following XSLT should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalk_Server_Project3.Envelope">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns0:Items" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ns0:Items">
        <ns0:Items>
            <!--i.e. Copy all Item elements and discard the Batch elements-->
            <xsl:copy-of select="ns0:Item"/>
        </ns0:Items>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716608/biztalk-2010-mapping-an-xsd-with-a-lot-of-elements-with-the-same-name/3718014#3718014) on how to convert a btm from a visual map to xslt

Comment: I thought of doing your second bullet point myself after I posted the question.  However, the debatching is done in a pipeline on the send port, and pipelines are done before maps on receive ports.