# Create Processing Instruction in BizTalk Map

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I know that in BizTalk maps, you can perserve processing instructions. However, the source XML that I will have will not have any processing instructions. However, I will need to create a processing instruction for the Target XML. I know I can write a custom XSLT to do this, however I would like to avoid that as I have the BizTalk map complete except for this.

Can I create processing instructions on the Target XML using only the available functoids in the BizTalk mapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than [using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716608/biztalk-2010-mapping-an-xsd-with-a-lot-of-elements-with-the-same-name/3718014#3718014) as you've mentioned, there is also an option to do this on the send port:

- Select the native `XmlTransmit` send pipeline
- Add your processing instructions to the
  `XmlAsmProcessingInstructions` property as per [this
  example](http://thoughtsofmarcus.blogspot.com/2010/02/adding-xml-stylesheet-reference-or.html)

Comment: Custom xslt seems to be the winner. An added bonus is that the xslt I wrote is a lot more efficient than what the mapper generated.