# BizTalk Mapper: Link between siblings

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I have the following XML that I need to transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRecords>
  <TestData>
    <Users>
      <User>
        <Id>BG123</Id>
        <Name>Bill Gates</Name>
      </User>
      <User>
    <Id>SN123</Id>
    <Name>Satya Nadella</Name>
  </User>
</Users>
<UserDetails>
  <UserDetail>
    <UserId>SN123</UserId>
    <CompanyName>Microsoft Corp</CompanyName>
  </UserDetail>
  <UserDetail>
    <UserId>
      <UserId>BG123</UserId>
      <CompanyName>Bill Gates Foundation</CompanyName>
    </UserId>
  </UserDetail>
</UserDetails>
```

I need to map this XML into the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRecords>
  <TestData>
    <Users>
      <User>
        <Id>BG123</Id>
        <Name>Bill Gates</Name>
        <CompanyName>Bill Gates Foundation</CompanyName>
      </User>
      <User>
        <Id>SN123</Id>
        <Name>Satya Nadella</Name>
        <CompanyName>Microsoft Corp</CompanyName>
      </User>
    </Users>
  </TestData>
</TestRecords>
```

When I loop over Users/User, I need to find the UserDetail where UserDetail/UserId is equal to the current User/Id

Thank you and best regards

Michael

Comment: It's quite common scenario. You can't do this using standard functiods. The simplest way to achieve this is Custom XSLT Template functiod. Try to google "BizTalk merge/join messages" e.g. https://adventuresinsidethemessagebox.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/merging-details-from-two-messages-using-a-biztalk-map/

Comment: thanks, I managed to make it work as explained in the blog post

Comment: @FCR Actually it is possible with standard functoids but sometimes may not be the most efficient way.  See my answer below.  P.S. The blog post you pointed to is that of a work colleague of mine.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do Custom XSLT as suggested by FCR the only other option when you have different looping structures is to have an intermediate schema and two maps.

[image: UserIn to UserInt]

Which produces

```
<TestRecords>
    <TestData>
        <Users>
            <User>
                <Id>BG123</Id>
                <Name>Bill Gates</Name>
                <UserDetails>
                    <UserID>SN123</UserID>
                    <CompanyName>Microsoft Corp</CompanyName>
                </UserDetails>
                <UserDetails>
                    <UserID>BG123</UserID>
                    <CompanyName>Bill Gates Foundation</CompanyName>
                </UserDetails>
            </User>
            <User>
                <Id>SN123</Id>
                <Name>Satya Nadella</Name>
                <UserDetails>
                    <UserID>SN123</UserID>
                    <CompanyName>Microsoft Corp</CompanyName>
                </UserDetails>
                <UserDetails>
                    <UserID>BG123</UserID>
                    <CompanyName>Bill Gates Foundation</CompanyName>
                </UserDetails>
            </User>
        </Users>
    </TestData>
</TestRecords>
```

Which you can then run through this second map to produce the desired outcome.

[image: UserInt to UserOut]

This will become very inefficient however if the second list is large.

Comment: Yes, I didn't thought about this. A little bit freaky solution, btw =)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common lookup pattern in `xslt` and there is also the opportunity to use `xsl:key` to create an index which can boost performance on large documents. [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718014/314291) if you need to convert a `.btm` to xslt.

(Also, I'm assuming that there isn't a double wrapper `UserId` at on the last `UserDetails/UserDetail` element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="userLookup" 
            match="/TestRecords/TestData/UserDetails/UserDetail" use="UserId"/>

   <!--identity template - copy everything by default --> 
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--i.e.match only Users in the first Users/User tree. Actually the explicit
       ancestor qualifier is redundant because of the other suppress template -->
   <xsl:template match="User[ancestor::Users]">
      <User>
         <xsl:copy-of select="child::*" />
         <CompanyName>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('userLookup', Id)/CompanyName"/>
        </CompanyName>
      </User>   
   </xsl:template>

   <!--Suppress the second userdetails part of the tree entirely -->
   <xsl:template match="UserDetails" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/isb05L)